# F# filter function - first argument's condition seems to be reversed

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I have a little weird experience with F# filter function today. The code is:

```
let rec filter : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list =
    fun isKept -> function
        | [] -> []
        | (x::xs) -> if isKept x then x::filter isKept xs
                     else filter isKept xs

let x = filter ((>) 1) [1; -5; -20; 30; -35; 40]
```

That code returns

```
val x : int list = [-5; -20; -35]
```

Problem is, as I pass a condition in the first argument (> 1), I expect it would filter out any list elements of the second argument that are greater 1, not the reverse.

Is there anything obviously clear that I couldn't spot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your filter function is fine. The problem is that this line of code:

```
let x = filter ((>) 1) [1; -5; -20; 30; -35; 40]
```

Is equivalent to this code if you use an explicit lambda instead of partially applying the `(>)` operator:

```
let x = filter (fun x -> 1 > x) [1; -5; -20; 30; -35; 40]
```

The reason for this is that the `(>)` function takes two arguments; even though the `1` appears to the right of the `(>)`, it's not passed as the "right" argument to the function. The solution is to either use `(<)` instead:

```
> let x = filter ((<) 1) [1; -5; -20; 30; -35; 40];;

val x : int list = [30; 40]
```

or to use an explicit lambda function to ensure you apply the arguments in the correct order:

```
> let x = filter (fun x -> x > 1) [1; -5; -20; 30; -35; 40];;

val x : int list = [30; 40]
```

Comment: Note that the complement of `(>)` is not `(<)` but `(<=)`.

Comment: @Frank You're correct -- but the question states `I expect it would filter out any list elements of the second argument that are greater [than] 1`. So `(<)` is needed to get the correct result.